# The query doesn t execute when I try to run it in php, it works in SQL execution

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I try to delte some information from the database, but the query doesn't work. I also tried to run it from the SQL and there it seems to work perfectly fine. It seems like there is something wrong with the parsing or maybe with the way I wrote it. I tried more options from the stackoverflow board and I commented the queries with the results I had when I tested them. Other details are that I run XAMPP 7.1.24.

Here is the code:

Delete and select functions php below

```
    function showAllData(){

                global $connection;
                $query = "SELECT * FROM users";
                $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);    
                if(!$result) {

                    die('Query Failed' . mysqli_error());

                                    }   



                while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
                $id = $row['id'];
                echo "<option value=''>'$id'</option>";

                                                         }       

        }

    function deleteRows() {

            global $connection;
            $id = $_POST['id'];



            $query = "DELETE FROM users WHERE id = " . $id; // Query FailedYou have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1

            $query = "DELETE FROM users WHERE id = '" . $id . "' "; // Doesn't delete anything from database

            $query = "DELETE FROM users WHERE id = ".$id; // Query FailedYou have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1


            $query = "DELETE FROM users WHERE id = $id";    // Query FailedYou have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1

            $query = "DELETE FROM users WHERE id IN ('" . $id . "')"; // Doesn t delete anything from database


            $query = "DELETE FROM users WHERE id = '" . $id . "' ";// Doesn t Delete anything from database

            /* $id = implode("' , '" ,  $_POST['id']);
                $query = "DELETE FROM Shopping WHERE id IN ('" . $id . "')";

                                Tested not working  */ 




                $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);

                if(!$result){

                    die('Query Failed' . mysqli_error($connection));
                }

        }
```

The Html code

```
    <?php include('db.php') ?>
    <?php include('functions.php') ?>
    <?php 
        if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

                    deleteRows();

                                    }

     ?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>

<!-- R Read -->



     <div class="container">

        <div class="col-sm-6">

            <form action="login_delete.php" method="post">

                <div class="container">
                    <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="username">Username</label>
                    <input type="text" name="username" class="form-control">
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="password">Password</label>
                            <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control">

                    </div>

                    <input class ="btn btn-primary" type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">

                    <div class="form-group">

                        <select name="id" id="">
                                <?php  

                                showAllData();

                                ?>

                        </select>

                    </div>

                    </div>

            </form>



            </div>

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The failures seem to indicate that `$id` is empty, so check the data in `$_POST`.

Comment: change $result="DELETE FROM user WHERE ID='$id'" and give the option value ='$id'

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the value in option :

Your code : 
`echo "<option value=''>'$id'</option>";`

The correction : `echo "<option value='$id'>'$id'</option>";`

One more things you have SQLInjection problem please take a look here : https://owasp.org/www-community/attacks/SQL_Injection